# Python multiprocessing pool.map raises IndexError

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cython

I've developed a utility using python/cython that sorts CSV files and generates stats for a client, but invoking pool.map seems to raise an exception before my mapped function has a chance to execute.  Sorting a small number of files seems to function as expected, but as the number of files grows to say 10, I get the below IndexError after calling pool.map.  Does anyone happen to recognize the below error?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

While the code is under NDA, the use-case is fairly simple:

**Code Sample:**

```
def sort_files(csv_files):
    pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size)
    sorted_dicts = pool.map(sort_file, csv_files, 1)
    return sorted_dicts

def sort_file(csv_file):
    print 'sorting %s...' % csv_file
    # sort code
```

**Output:**

```
File "generic.pyx", line 17, in generic.sort_files (/users/cyounker/.pyxbld/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pyrex/generic.c:1723)
    sorted_dicts = pool.map(sort_file, csv_files, 1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The traceback you show contains a different variable name (`sorted_dict`) than the one in your code sample (`results`), which suggests you aren't posting actual code that runs and generates the error.

Comment: Typo on my part -- the results variable was from a very similar function that calculates stats.  I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The IndexError is an error you get somewhere in sort_file(), i.e. in a subprocess.  It is re-raised by the parent process.  Apparently `multiprocessing` doesn't make any attempt to inform us about where the error really comes from (e.g. on which lines it occurred) or even just what argument to sort_file() caused it.  I hate `multiprocessing` even more :-(

Comment: Correct!  I discovered one of my csv files was missing a column.  Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 4):

Check further up in the command output.
In Python 3.4 at least, `multiprocessing.pool` will helpfully print a `RemoteTraceback` above the parent process traceback. You'll see something like:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/path/to/your/code/here.py", line 80, in sort_file
    something = row[index]
IndexError: list index out of range
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generic.pyx", line 17, in generic.sort_files (/users/cyounker/.pyxbld/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pyrex/generic.c:1723)
    sorted_dicts = pool.map(sort_file, csv_files, 1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

In the case above, the code raising the error is at `/path/to/your/code/here.py", line 80`

see also [debugging errors in python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080650/debugging-errors-in-python-multiprocessing)